# Javascript-UI-Element (Bootstrap-switch) not working when loaded dynamicaly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mouseevent

I try to write a wizard. Therefor I got a display-element:

```
<div class="ERd">
   <div class="wizardImage"><img src="wizimg/test.png"/></div>
   <div class="wizardRight" id="wr"><h3>Hi folks</h3>
      <div>Lets switch! <br/><br/>
         <div class="make-switch switch-mini" data-on-label="AN" data-off-label="AUS" id="sw1">
            <input class="toggle" type="checkbox"/>
         </div>number1<br/><br/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And different contents:

```
<div class="wizardContainer" id="f1">
   <div class="version">1.0.0</div>
   <div class="image">img.png</div>
   <div class="heading">Step 1</div>
   <div class="content">This is magic
      <div class="make-switch switch-mini" data-on-label="AN" data-off-label="AUS" id="sw2">
         <input class="toggle" type="checkbox"/>
      </div>number2<br/>
   </div>
</div>
```

I fill the display element with the contents:

```
function DisplayStep(id) {
    var container = $('#' + id);

    var wizVersion = container.find('.version').text();
    var wizImage = container.find('.image').text();
    var wizCategory = container.find('.category').text();
    var wizHeader = container.find('.heading').text();
    var wizContent = container.find('.content');

    $('.wizardSubtitle').text(wizCategory);
    $('.wizardImage img').attr('src', './wizimg/' + wizImage);
    $('.wizardRight h3').text(wizHeader);
    $('.wizardRight div').empty();
    $('.wizardRight div').append(wizContent);
}
Display('f1');
```

The correct content is displayed, but dynamic functions do not seem to work. To be precise the  sw1 works, sw2 doesnt. (sw2 is also rendered correctly, but the seems to be a layer "above" that prevents the mouse-events to be sent to sw2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arg. Got to answer myself this one. The problem seems to be, that copying the wizard-data creates two elements with the same ID.

Moving instead of copying solved the problem:

```
container.find('.content').appendTo('#wr');
```

Sometimes writing down is half way to the solution. I keep this here, cause I think it might be useful for others, too